# Why the sketch size and amount of RAM used by Arduino DUE is more than Arduino MEGA 2560

Tags: arduino

Can anybody please tell me why due sketches occupy more RAM compared to Mega for the same code. I need to make an analysis.

Please help to solve my query.

Answer (score 4):

It's because they have different microcontrollers: Arduino Mega 2560 has a 8-bit AVR ATMega2560 microcontroller and Arduino Due has a 32-bit ARM Cortex-M3 microcontroller.

**RAM**

Variables are smaller in 8-bit architectures than in 32-bit architectures. For example: `int` is 2 bytes long in Mega 2560 but is 4 bytes long in Due.

Because of that, a program in Due will use more RAM than a program in Mega 2560 (and any other ATMega-based Arduino board like Uno and Leonardo).

**Sketch size**

The reason is similar to RAM: most instructions in 8-bit AVR architectures are 16 bits long while in ARM architectures, the majority of instructions are 32 bits long.